# NSString isEqualToString issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I am making an app and am trying to use isEqualToString to compare to strings I know are the same. However, this code is not working

```
- (void)uui {
    array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Path2];
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array2 objectAtIndex:3]];
    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Partly Cloudy"];
    NSLog(@"%@ , %@", string, string2);
    if ([string isEqualToString:string2]) {
        NSLog(@"frack");
    }
}
```

This is what I get in the log

```
2013-01-02 23:13:27.512 My Sky[3788:907] Partly Cloudy  , Partly Cloudy
```

As you can see, they are the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: May be the string has extra spaces at the end. Try checking both has same character length.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No the strings are not equal.
From your log:

```
Partly Cloudy  , Partly Cloudy
```

There is a extra space after the first string.
Check with this code:

```
- (void)uui
{
  array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Path2];
  string = (NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:3];
  NSString *string2 = @"Partly Cloudy";  
  NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"%@ , %@", trimmedString, string2);
   if ([trimmedString isEqualToString:string2])
   {
     NSLog(@"frack");
   }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: Thanks for your comment :) Please check my edited answer, I have added a solution.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: With Pleasure :)

Comment: Please get rid of both needless uses of `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks for your valuable comment, I edited my answer :)